# Fixed position in a button in a scrollable view/component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, office-fabric

I have a callout (office fabric ui) with data. When the data is to much the callout area is scrollable. However I want a button in the footer/beneath this data in the same callout component to ALWAYS be visible. I have tried to add "position: absolute/fixed" for the button. It stays in place, but the data in the scrollable parts "Pushes" the button down, even if its not visible. See image.

[image]

Above you can see the "Done" button have a absolute/fixed position. Its always visible, but its gets out by the tags, even if its scrollable.I want it to be as a footer in the scrollable view and always shown there, as opposed to be beneath woth a margin. See the second picture for the behaviour I want to achieve.

[image]

Tried to recreate the problem in my sandbox with my code. Not entirely the same but similar:
https://codesandbox.io/s/6v7m7mk8vz?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  height: 6em;
  width: 10em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 17px;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <ul><li>0<li>1<li>2<li>3<li>4<li>5<li>6<li>7<li>8<li>9</ul>
    <footer><button>Footered button</button></footer>
  </div>
</section>
```